# What was incriminating about the picture of Agent Simmons?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In S02E05 of *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* (“A Hen in the Wolf House”), Raina threatens Agent Coulson with her intention to send a picture of Agent Simmons to all HYDRA employees, because she knows that

> Simmons is working undercover as a HYDRA employee. What she doesn't know is that Simmons used her past with S.H.I.E.L.D. as part of the cover, so HYDRA already knows she is a former agent.

The picture is simply of Simmons eating lunch. The film screen in her hand is already camouflaged as a taco wrap, complete with the restaurant's logo on it. **So what exactly about the photo is incriminating?**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

H.Y.D.R.A. has recovered the film screen (we see it in Bobbie's hand) so they must know that it was disguised as a taco wrapper when they found it (although we don't know how).

[image]

Thus the image of Simmons with the very **same wrapper right next to where they recovered the screen** is pretty damaging.

Comment: The film screen being held by Bobbi in the screenshot is a different one. Simmons had that one in her desk, but switched it to Kenny's desk when they came searching.

Comment: @Omegacron You are mistaken I am afraid. Bobbie already had the film in her hand when we see Simmons look at *another* film in her drawer.

Comment: Accepted! That was the detail that made it click, then - I missed that.